# Overloading with 'different' return type

Tags: c#, overloading

I have always read that overloaded methods should *always* return the same type whenever possible.

However I've come upon a scenario which I really don't know if it could be considered as having different return types or not.

Consider the following implementation to obtain the permutations of all elements of a given collection taken `k` at a time where the elements the make up the permutation are aggregated to the consumer's needs.

```
public static IEnumerable<Q> GetPermutations<T, Q>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int k, Func<IEnumerable<T>, Q> aggregator)
{
    if (k <= 0)
        return Enumerable.Empty<Q>();

    return collection.getPermutations(k).Select(p => aggregator(p));
}

private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> getPermutations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> set, int k) =>
           k == 0 ? new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }
                  : set.SelectMany((item, index) => set.SkipAt(index).getPermutations(k - 1).Select(p => new[] { item }.Concat(p)));

private static IEnumerable<T> SkipAt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int index)
{
    var counter = 0;

    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        if (counter != index)
        {
            yield return item;
        }

        counter++;
    }
}
```

Now I want to define an overload that takes no `aggregator` and simply returns each permutation as an `IEnumerable<T>`.

My first implementation looked as follows:

```
 public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPermutations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int k)
        => GetPermutations(collection, k, p => p);
```

Pretty straightforward. But then I realized that I am in someway changing the return type of the method. If inspected in intellisense, the first returns `IEnumerable<Q>` while the second returns `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` and the type parameter `Q` dissapears.

Should this be any cause of concern? Can it create confussion and should be avoided if possible? Technically the return type does not change, as `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` *is* an `IEnumerable<Q>` but it still caught my eye when reviewing the code as I don't recall seeing anything similar before.

The workaround I immediately thought of was to make `aggregator` optional, but this runs into its own problems:

```
public static IEnumerable<Q> GetPermutations<T, Q>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int k, Func<IEnumerable<T>, Q> aggregator = null)
{
    if (k <= 0)
        return Enumerable.Empty<Q>();

    var myAggregator = aggregator ?? new Func<IEnumerable<T>, Q)(p => p); //Compile time error, no implicit conversion from `IEnumerable<T>` to `Q`
    return collection.getPermutations(k).SelectMany(p => new[] { myAggregator(p) });
}
```

Note that the second type parameter `Q` is necessary due to our needs and the corner case provided by `string` being an `IEnumerable<char>`. An aggregator of type `Func<IEnumerable<T>, T>` for instance would not work:

```
var str = "1234";
var permutations = str.GetPermutations(4, p => Concat(p)); // compile time error, `string` is not a `char`.
```

Is the proposed overload acceptable or is there a workaround I am not considering available to make the optional argument solution work?

Comment: Short questions are better.

Comment: Do you have any source for different return types being a bad practice?
I think you are confusing that with: it's not possible to create overloads with only different return types, having the same parameter number/types.

Comment: @PetrVávro Its confusing, specially whith languages that have implict typing like C#. There are very few examples in the framework for instance where return types are different, being preferable to change the name of the method. Its true there is no general consensus but googling and polling coworkers I generally found opinions based towards avoiding the issue if possible and I agree.

Comment: @InBetween I agree with that. But having two overloads on a Generic method that just return different types based on the parameters doesn't seem like breaking convention. For example the `IEnumerable.Average` extension method does have different return types, based on the parameter that is provided. I'd say your case wouldn't lead to confusion as well.

Comment: @PetrVávro I agree it's fine to have different return types for different overloads. `GroupBy` lets you do [something very similar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.100).aspx) - if you provide a projection from the input types to some other type, of course you get a different type out.